# How can I setup up JUNIT on windows to work with Sublime and command line?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I just downloaded junit.jar and hamcrest-core.jar but I do not what else to do so that I can run tests with the command line. I am using Sublime Text 3 to write java code and then using the command line. How can I get this setup to be able to run tests?

Comment: You might want to check the user guide on https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Generally, with any Java project of non-trivial size, you'll want to use a build tool such as Maven or Gradle. Starter projects for these generally include a Junit test alongside the stub code.